# How to find the inflection points for Newton's Diverging Parabola (campinaformis cum ovali)?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am currently doing a project on Newton's/Mobius' classification of cubics of the form $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$. One of the various graphs is $y^2=(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all real roots. I know this graph has $1$ inflection point, but I cannot derive a generalised point. The second derivative test becomes too complicated since I have to square root both sides. I was wondering If anyone had another way to show that it has to have $1$ inflection point. Thank you!

Comment: Try this: take a general point $P=(\xi,\eta)$ on the curve, draw the tangent line $\ell$ to the curve at $P$, and adjust $P$ so that the third intersection of $\ell$ with the curve is at $P$. Should involve a cubic equation in the coordinates. (You know, I’m sure, that as long as your cubic has no repeated roots, there are exactly the two (symmetric) inflection points.) Notice that my suggestion does not involve second derivative.